# Como cálculo los días transcurridos entre dos fechas, Fecha Inicial – Fecha Final

Tags: sql-server

Tengo dos campos que almacenan la fecha inicial de un contrato y la fecha final del mismo, necesito calcular los días transcurridos de entre estas 2 fechas, ejemplo:

01/05/2019 a 05/05/2019 = 4 días

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], edita y muestra que has intentado

Comment: aquí encontrarás lo que buscas, solo deberás checar respecto al formato que espera `DATEDIFF()` pues tu formato es distinto https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/8e5afdad-64bc-4caf-ab7d-f175c36aeb34/como-obtener-diferencia-de-dias-entre-2-fechas-con-datediff-sin-contar-fines-de-semana?forum=sqlserveres

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que estas buscando es algo asi:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2019-01-05','2019-05-05) as dias
FROM tuTabla;
```

Comment: Como detalle, creo que Daniel se refiere a dos columnas, así que sería algo como <<SELECT DATEDIFF(day,fecha_inicial,fecha_final) as dias
FROM tuTabla;>>.